# Does Lightroom have a healing brush?

Tags: lightroom, software, post-processing

Does Lightroom have a healing brush?

I'm aware of the spot-healing capability, for some corrections I need a brush to paint the healing. Photoshop has this, but it slows my workflow down to have to keep jumping into PS to correct aberrations.

I'd love to do this directly in Lightroom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short Answer:  No

Lightroom has a spot healing tool, which will heal a circular area of the image.
Alas, you cannot paint the healing on in an ad-hoc shape.  In order to remove a line (like an overhead power line or similar), you have to create a row of circular healing spots.

I *long* for the day when this changes!

*(Note: this is written as of Lightroom 3.0)*

Comment: The answer also applies to Lightroom 4.0.

Comment: It also applies to 5.6 and 5.7.

Answer (score 4):

The spot-healing brush is a dual-mode brush. There is a `Clone` setting as well as a `Heal` setting. The heal setting is much more effective at generating "healing content", if you will. I believe it is based off of the same healing brush found in Adobe Camera Raw, so it should serve the same purpose.

Comment: Does it support painting? For example, if I have a power-line, can I just paint over the line and have it remove the power-line? I can with the healing brush in photoshop (which is different than the spot healing in photoshop). Can I do the same with Lightroom?

Comment: @Alan: To be honest, I don't think I've ever tried it that way, so I am not sure. Are you talking about Photoshop CS5 and its content-aware fill features? Or a previous version of Photoshop?

Comment: Nope. PS has two different healing tools. A brush that lets you paint (similar to clone), and a spot-heal brush, that specifically lets you point-and-click on a spot to heal. The latter is what Lightroom has, and it's great for dustspots, dirt, etc, but lousy for powerlines, etc.

Comment: @Alan: I just did a little testing, and it appears it is just a spot heal, not a brush heal. I only have version 2, however, so I am not sure if this has improved in version 3.